# Powershell get a outer variable in a foreach sequence

Tags: powershell

```
    PS C:\Projects> 
    get-childitem  -recurse 
 |  where { $_.Extension -eq ".csproj" }
 | foreach { Get-Content $_.FullName 
          | foreach { $_.Length } }
```

This prints the line size of every line in a csproj (pretty pointless true). How can I also output a outer variable (so to speak) when I've dived further. So for example let's say for pointeless reasons I wanted to have it print the filename too so I would get:

Dog.csproj: 10
Dog.csproj: 50
Dog.csproj: 4
Cat.csproj: 100
Cat.csproj: 440

I figure I want to do something like this but this does not work obviously, (and yes the example is pointless)

```
  PS C:\Projects> 
        get-childitem  -recurse 
     |  STORE THIS IN $filename | where { $_.Extension -eq ".csproj" }
     | foreach { Get-Content $_.FullName 
              | foreach { $filename ":"  $_.Length } }
```

I played with tee-object and outputvariable but I'm a bit lost. If a powershell guru could answer it would help, also if you could recommend a book or resource that explains the language  syntax fundamentals rather than API monkey stuff of COM/WMI/VB etc.. (that seems most of what I came across) it would be most appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This the straightforward way:

```
`gci . -r "*.csproj" | % { $name = $_.name; gc $_.fullname |
         % { $name + ": " + $_.length }  }`
```

If you don't yet know the abbreviations, that is equivalent to:

```
`Get-ChildItem . -recurse "*.csproj" | 
      foreach { $name = $_.name; Get-Content $_.fullname | 
      foreach { $name + ": " + $_.length }  }`
```

As for a book recommendation, it has to be Bruce Payette's book:  [http://www.amazon.com/Windows-PowerShell-Action-Bruce-Payette/dp/1932394907](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1932394907)

Mike

Answer (score 0):

```
get-childitem -recurse -filter *.csproj | select @{n="FileName";e={$_.FullName}},@{n="Lines";e={ $(cat $_.FullName).count}}
```

It gives an output like:

```
+--------------------------+---------+
|         FileName         |  Lines  |
---------------------------|---------+
| D:\Scripts\test1.csproj  | 867     |
| D:\Scripts\test2.csproj  | 1773    |
+--------------------------|---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
dir -r -fo *.csproj | select @{n="FileName";e={$_.FullName}},@{n="LineLong";e={ cat $_.fullName | foreach {$_.length}}}
```